# How do I compare the cursor position on an two dimentional array after I move it with the keyboard?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a two dimensions array that draw a text map on the screen and
I am moving a character on the screen using 'WASD'.
I want to test the map limits so that the character won't go out of bounds.

Any clue?

Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool GameOver = false;
        int playerX = 1;
        int playerY = 1;
        char[,] myCharArray = new char[16, 8];
        string[] lol = new string[8];
        lol[0] = "----------------";
        lol[1] = "-              -";
        lol[2] = "-              -";
        lol[3] = "-              -";
        lol[4] = "-              -";
        lol[5] = "-              -";
        lol[6] = "-              -";
        lol[7] = "----------------";

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            char[] letters = lol[i].ToCharArray();

            for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
            {
                myCharArray[j, i] = letters[j];
            }
        }

        do
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
                {
                    if (playerX == j && playerY == i)
                    {
                        Console.Write('*');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write(myCharArray[j, i]);
                    }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            }

            ConsoleKeyInfo pressedKey = Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine(pressedKey.Key.ToString());
            if (pressedKey.Key.ToString() == "A")
            {                    
                playerX--;
            }
            if (pressedKey.Key.ToString() == "S")
            {
                playerY++;
            }
            if (pressedKey.Key.ToString() == "D")
            {
                playerX++;
            }
            if (pressedKey.Key.ToString() == "W")
            {
                playerY--;
            }
            Console.Clear();
        } while (GameOver == false);

    }
```

Comment: Yes, it did. Thanks.

Comment: Cool. But 4 years to digest seems long. Good Luck!

Comment: LOL. It took me 4 years to remember to check my inbox. I'm ashamed but it is the true.

Answer (score 0):

If condition here:

```
  if (pressedKey.Key.ToString() == "A")
            {   
                //check if move left is possible
                if(playerX != 0)                  
                    playerX--;
            }
```

**EDIT** Please find some enriched version, figure out the rules alone :].

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace FunnyStuff
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool GameOver = true;
            int playerX = 1;
            int playerY = 1;

            int[] enemy = new int[2];
            Random random = new Random();
            int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 100);
            enemy[0] = random.Next(1, 15);
            enemy[1] = random.Next(1, 6);
            char[,] myCharArray = new char[16, 8];
            string[] lol = new string[8];
            lol[0] = "----------------";
            lol[1] = "-              -";
            lol[2] = "-              -";
            lol[3] = "-              -";
            lol[4] = "-              -";
            lol[5] = "-              -";
            lol[6] = "-              -";
            lol[7] = "----------------";

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                char[] letters = lol[i].ToCharArray();

                for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
                {
                    myCharArray[j, i] = letters[j];
                }
            }

            do
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
                    {
                        if (playerX == j && playerY == i)
                        {
                            Console.Write('*');
                        }
                        else if (enemy[0] == j && enemy[1] == i)
                        {
                            Console.Write('+');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.Write(myCharArray[j, i]);
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

                int rx = random.Next(-1, 2);
                int ry = random.Next(-1, 2);
                enemy[0] = (rx+enemy[0] != 1 || rx+enemy[0] != 14) ? rx+enemy[0] : enemy[0];
                enemy[1] = (ry + enemy[1] != 1 || ry + enemy[0] != 6) ? ry + enemy[1] : enemy[1];

                ConsoleKeyInfo pressedKey = Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine(pressedKey.Key.ToString());
                if (pressedKey.Key.ToString() == "A")
                {
                    if (playerX != 1) 
                    playerX--;
                }
                if (pressedKey.Key.ToString() == "S")
                {
                    if (playerY != 6)
                    playerY++;
                }
                if (pressedKey.Key.ToString() == "D")
                {
                    if (playerX != 14)
                    playerX++;
                }
                if (pressedKey.Key.ToString() == "W")
                {
                    if (playerY != 1) 
                    playerY--;
                }

                if (playerX == enemy[0] && playerY == enemy[1])
                {
                    GameOver = false;
                }

                Console.Clear();
            } while (GameOver );

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a start, thank you.

When you move you can go on the limits if you press the key a second time so I think that the best way will be a loop.

I'll try that.

Comment: Hmm. It's already in the loop. Set GameOver to TRUE and add some condition when game should end. GL!

Comment: This will make it work.  
    'if (myCharArray[playerX-1,playerY] != '-')
                        {
                            playerX--;
                        }'

Comment: Fine, but consider that a lot of things have to be done in 'your' if. Exactly there are two more things more than in mine :].

Comment: Yep but if you ran the code with your fix it will not work as supposed to. Mine does. =]

Comment: Some minor index issues :]. Find some variation about your game in post. GL!